# Left-align denominator in MathJax

Tags: support, mathjax

I want to be able to create an example of modus ponens using MathJax, in the following form:

$$\frac{\begin{array}{l}
   \text{If it is raining, then the grass is wet} \\
   \text{It is raining}
  \end{array}}{
    \text{The grass is wet}}
$$

but I want the conclusion line to be left aligned, in the same way that the premises are.  This is the code that I use:

```
\frac{\begin{array}{l}
   \text{If it is raining, then the grass is wet} \\
   \text{It is raining}
  \end{array}}{
\text{The grass is wet}}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use `\frac`, it is meant to be used only with fractions. Use a bigger array, and insert horizontal lines `\hline`at appropriate places.

```
\begin{array}{l}
\text{if it is raining, then the grass is wet}\\
\text{it is raining}\\
\hline
\text{the grass is wet}
\end{array}
```

$$
\begin{array}{l}
\text{if it is raining, then the grass is wet}\\
\text{it is raining}\\
\hline
\text{the grass is wet}
\end{array}
$$

The TeXperts may know of more sophisticated and flexible ways of going about this.

Comment: Why does the "Tour Page" on Meta say: "Don't ask about: Questions about typesetting equations"? - Was it simply copied from https://math.stackexchange.com/tour ?